# List all books from Book Library (Django App with Tastypie) in Kivy app

Tags: kivy

I learn Kivy. I have Django app with CRUD function (Books Library) and API for this (Tastypie).

How can look "algorithm" building applications with a list of all my book? What component to use to list and how to retrieve data from the API and to display them?

> mysite.com/api/books/?format=json

json:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 8}, "objects": [{"title": "Kivy book", "description": "Cool book", "id": 1, "page_count": 155}]}
```

Can anyone provide the code for this simple example?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is exactly the problem you are experiencing? What have you tried? Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921910/python-urllib2-receive-json-response-from-url) of how to transform a JSON (from an URL) to a Python dict. As for components of Kivy you might want to take a look on [ListView](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from my understanding you are trying to achieve. It is based on the simplest [ListView example](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html). Please notice that I created an extended JSON version from the example you provided. Also, when you want to use the url, you have to substitute the 2 commented lines. The method for loading the json is `load` (for io input) and not `loads` (for string input).

```
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import json
import urllib2

class MainView(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 2
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)


        the_string_json = '{"meta": {"previous": null, "total_count": 8, "offset": 0, "limit": 20, "next": null}, "objects": [{"id": 1, "page_count": 155, "description": "Cool book", "title": "Kivy book 1"}, {"id": 1, "page_count": 155, "description": "Cool book", "title": "Kivy book 2"}, {"id": 1, "page_count": 155, "description": "Cool book", "title": "Kivy book 3"}]}'
        the_dict = json.loads(the_string_json)

        # Substitute the previous two lines for this ones:
        # the_io_json = urllib2.urlopen('mysite.com/api/books/?format=json')
        # the_dict = json.load(the_io_json)

        list_view = ListView(
            item_strings=[book['title'] for book in the_dict['objects']])

        self.add_widget(list_view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(MainView(width=800))
```