# How to use Python to execute a cURL command?

Tags: python, curl

I want to execute a curl command in Python.

Usually, I just need to enter the command in the terminal and press the return key. However, I don't know how it works in Python.

The command shows below:

```
curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=mykeyhere
```

There is a `request.json` file to be sent to get a response.

I searched a lot and got confused. I tried to write a piece of code, although I could not fully understand it and it didn't work.

```
import pycurl
import StringIO

response = StringIO.StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=mykeyhere')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, response.write)
c.setopt(c.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json','Accept-Charset: UTF-8'])
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, '@request.json')
c.perform()
c.close()
print response.getvalue()
response.close()
```

The error message is `Parse Error`. How to get a response from the server correctly?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667509/curl-alternative-in-python

Comment: FWIW, have you considered using [pycurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/) the _"Python binding to cURL"_ ? Depending your needs, it might be more efficient/convenient than invoking the command line utility behind the scene.

Comment: Do you need to use cURL? Have you considered [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)? Might be simpler, especially if you're new to python, which tends to be unforgiving.

Comment: I just wanted to also point you to this great answer on how to execute a shell command in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/92395/778533

Answer (score 325):

For the sake of simplicity, you should consider using the [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) library.

An example with JSON response content would be something like:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')
r.json()
```

If you look for further information, in the [Quickstart](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/) section, they have lots of working examples.

For your specific curl translation:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=mykeyhere'
payload = open("request.json")
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: For some reason Requests is eating up the response data..  
My response should be something like `One=1&Two=2&Three=3` but instead it is returning `One=1&&Three=3`  I cURLed it and the response is coming through in the format I am expecting.. weird bug.

Comment: Please @tricknology, try to search for the bug and, if you do not happen to find a proper solution, post a new question.

Comment: Should anyone else happen to see this, the reason why that was happening to me is that I was giving a string as my payload instead of a dictionary object.

Comment: It seems there's a small typo in the headers, which should read `'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'`

Comment: thanks for reporting @StephenLead. I have just corrected it.

Comment: Opening the file and parsing JSON before sending it is needlessly inefficient. You parse the JSON then convert it back into a string with json.dumps(). This is a bad answer.

Comment: `Requests` is an extra dependency you need to install and manage. For a simple solution using just standard library, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13921930/111995

Comment: This is all very nice, but doesn't actually answer the question the OP posed?

Answer (score 199):

Use [curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com). It'll convert almost any curl command into Python, Node.js, PHP, R, Go and more.

**Example:**

```bash
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/asdfasdfasdf
```

becomes this in Python

```py
import requests

json_data = {
    'text': 'Hello, World!',
}

response = requests.post('https://hooks.slack.com/services/asdfasdfasdf', json=json_data)
```

Comment: Curl converter does not seem to work well with fields, such as `curl -F name=John -F shoesize=11 https://example.com/`. It treats them as files.

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/ was very useful!

Answer (score 38):

```
curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=mykeyhere
```

its Python implementation looks like this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = {
    'key': 'mykeyhere',
}

with open('request.json') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('\n', '')

response = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search', params=params, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Check *[this link](https://curlconverter.com/python/)*, it will help convert cURL commands to Python, PHP and Node.js

Answer (score 28):

```
import requests
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=mykeyhere"
data = requests.get(url).json
```

maybe?

if you are trying to send a file

```
files = {'request_file': open('request.json', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print r.text, print r.json
```

ahh thanks @LukasGraf now i better understand what his original code is doing

```
import requests,json
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=mykeyhere"
my_json_data = json.load(open("request.json"))
req = requests.post(url,data=my_json_data)
print req.text
print 
print req.json # maybe?
```

Comment: That doesn't include data from the `requests.json` file though, and doesn't set the `Content-Type: application/json` header - also, this will send a `GET` request, not a `POST`.

Comment: `curl -d @<file>` will read the *fields* to post from `<file>` - that's not the same as file upload.

Comment: @LukasGraf thanks :) ... I dont use curl much (read: almost never)

Comment: One small note, `data = requests.get(url).json` should be `data = requests.get(url).json()`

Comment: in 2014 it was  a property now its a function :) good call though

Answer (score 15):

My answer is WRT python 2.6.2.

```
import commands

status, output = commands.getstatusoutput("curl -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -k -u (few other parameters required) -X GET https://example.org -s")

print output
```

I apologize for not providing the required parameters 'coz it's confidential.

Comment: If you need to use some specials options from curl like --resolve this is the way. Thank you.

Comment: how can i only get the returned json without the tabular stat

Answer (score 13):

I had this exact question because I had to do something to retrieve content, but all I had available was an old version of Python with inadequate SSL support. If you're on an older MacBook, you know what I'm talking about. In any case, `curl` runs fine from a shell (I suspect it has modern SSL support linked in) so sometimes you want to do this without using [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

You can use the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to execute `curl` and get at the retrieved content:

```py
import subprocess

# 'response' contains a []byte with the retrieved content.
# use '-s' to keep curl quiet while it does its job, but
# it's useful to omit that while you're still writing code
# so you know if curl is working
response = subprocess.check_output(['curl', '-s', baseURL % page_num])
```

Python 3's `subprocess` module also contains [`.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) with a number of useful options.

Comment: I having the same issues with the company MacBook with proxy security analysis. I'll write my wapper around CURL to process some requests.

Answer (score 5):

I use `os` library.

```
import os

os.system("sh script.sh")
```

`script.sh` literally only contains the curl.

Answer (score 3):

**PYTHON 3**

*Only works within UNIX (Linux / Mac) (!)*

Executing a cURL with Python 3 and parsing its JSON data.

```
import shlex
import json
import subprocess

# Make sure that cURL has Silent mode (--silent) activated
# otherwise we receive progress data inside err message later
cURL = r"""curl -X --silent POST http://www.test.testtestest/ -d 'username=test'"""

lCmd = shlex.split(cURL) # Splits cURL into an array

p = subprocess.Popen(lCmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate() # Get the output and the err message

json_data = json.loads(out.decode("utf-8"))

print(json_data) # Display now the data
```

Sometimes you also need to install these dependencies on UNIX if you experience strange errors:

```
# Dependencies  
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt install curl
```

Answer (score 1):

if you os supporting curl you can do something like this:

```
import os

os.system("curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=mykeyhere")
```

I'm using this way... And I think you can use this too!

by the way.. the module "os" is auto-installing when you install python.
soo, you don't need to install packages ;)

Answer (score 1):

use requests  lib.. this code is :

```
curl -LH "Accept: text/x-bibliography; style=apa" https://doi.org/10.5438/0000-0C2G
```

equal to this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/x-bibliography; style=apa',
}

r = requests.get('https://doi.org/10.5438/0000-0C2G', headers=headers)


print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

To summarize all the options:

1. execute the command in Python using a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

For example:

```
import subprocess

# The command you would type in the terminal
command = ["curl", "https://www.example.com"]

# Run the command
result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

# Get the output and error message (if any)
output = result.stdout
error = result.stderr

# Check if it was successful
if result.returncode == 0:
    print("Success:")
    print(output)
else:
    print("Error:")
    print(error)
```

2. Using [pycurl library](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl): An interface to libcurl
3. Use curl alternative to create an HTTP request. For example using `requests` library in Python.

Here is the full explanation link: [Using cURL with Python and it's alternative](https://serpapi.com/blog/python-curl-and-alternative/).

Answer (score -2):

This is one approach:

```
Import os
import requests 
Data = os.execute(curl URL)
R= Data.json()
```

Comment: os.system instead of os.execute, and requests seems unnecessary in this case