# CURL headers from PHP to python requests library?

Tags: php, python, curl

I am currently translating code from PHP:

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

How do I set these variables in python's requests?

This is what i have so far

output = requests.post(url, headers=headers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use python to execute a curl command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491090/how-to-use-python-to-execute-a-curl-command)

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Did you not manage to figure out any of it at all? Not even how to pass the headers?

Comment: Just take the values from `$headers` and make a `headers` dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()

c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
c.setopt(c.USERPWD,USER+':'+PASSWORD)
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.setopt(c.HEADERFUNCTION, header_function)
c.perform()
```

Comment: I can't use the requests library no?