# Curl command in Python 3

Tags: python, curl, google-oauth

I want to execute a curl with command in python.

Usually, I just need enter the command in terminal and press return key.

The command shows below:

```
curl -H "`oauth2l header --json key.json mobileinsights`"  https://mobileinsights.googleapis.com/v2/networks
```

The result is in json format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use python to execute a curl command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491090/how-to-use-python-to-execute-a-curl-command)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You could use `subprocess` to run `oauth2l header --json key.json mobileinsights` from Python... Then use whatever HTTP library in python to pass a header

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) module to run your shell command.

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.check_output('curl -H "`oauth2l header --json 
key.json mobileinsights`" https://mobileinsights.googleapis.com/v2/networks', shell=True)
```

Then, use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to parse the JSON data returned by the server.

```
import json
result_json = json.loads(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may load an OS and JSON load modules and then run
os.execute(curl URL) store it in any variable then convert it into JSON format with JSON load module