# Run curl script in python

Tags: python, loops, curl

I wrote a script to run the curl command 100 times. The curl command works on the terminal. But when I add it as a variable in the python string variable, I get Invalid syntax error. I copied the curl from the browser. What am I missing

Here is my curl command

```
curl 'https://www.example.com/api/security/v2/security/authorize' -H 'cookie: check=true; AMCVS_65D316D751E563EC0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; mbox=session#d04ba89c86f54832a0585749aa46fc02#1553027525|PC#d04ba89c86f54832a0585749aa46fc02.17_16#1616270465; AMCV_65D316D751E563EC0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-1303530583%7CMCIDTS%7C17975%7CMCMID%7C34457710901731852771086841945878510845%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1553032862s%7CNONE%7CMCAAMLH-1553630462%7C7%7CMCAAMB-1553630462%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-17982%7CvVersion%7C3.3.0; RT="sl=1&ss=1553025660875&tt=3538&obo=0&bcn=%2F%2F36a3fec2.akstat.io%2F&sh=1553025664433%3D1%3A0%3A3538&dm=example.com&si=a71a0de4-27c6-4c1a-806e-137e6c895955&ld=1553025664433"; s_gpv_pn=HP%3ASWA%3Aexample%20Homepage; s_cc=true; akavpau_prod_fullsite=1553025700~id=91b5f44270a63e4fa47dfa8e4734170e' -H 'x-5ku220jw-b: -kzvuvq' -H 'origin: https://www.example.com' -H 'x-5ku220jw-c: A9ruipdpAQAAiGHiRkYp3f3DrWYPKZVfar1Ol_KL0TJZ45wOBoAMWp5BJsvcAawUHfCuctHLwH8AABszAAAAAA==' -H 'x-user-experience-id: f6d89ffd-417e-417c-b380-aa29dc4dac4f' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'x-5ku220jw-a: -gAl0zNf2niU1IiB8nEK-XDD9pte-YgvkwM_28ALqfwo-I7G2gH305BQhtly8TgsQsrw2YyZ8nrF9Crg25vD2nSgDXBgeg-ZkjhbWaqi0vYBtTkg8bMc70Auowl-x5pZx5BuoaOHeIR1o5cN-Lcsx8ALx3oTTakH-EOY269phIOu8naLWzlQXLMgWz756toxlzMTmEMuycrlVf742vrB0IOkAzbTD0MCgc0sVZEXi6Ah18WdWtSHiXwe28MQj80D94r46zzQtnS6xnak83a2bqYPAWAgbgOiYn7HTI7_bYkU6EfDPhVZ-lgLkEsuG3tZ-n7wtaA37fA1h6Mb8LyH=Eae=Z3G0y7sW4B41d3Tbee-a3ZT0sO4GEyhhbAY=Er8ZEVS-Ill09B84I7Y0ng4eDllklgk0uU6=cpT0zsb7sauhWDkAokY2tzY-nATyZ-ZyTs576M38qBgswDbULNFeIz=DDweWlB87ek07VtT2eiDoarQD7OioEVsSpaSrIh9tngu6cB3kaB4kdM420wUtTDpGWbF2npF04rgD0kYTuxThWkkG86L2LNZAfW46Iag-VZZWlMTU6r54RMgxtMBOZSTo7z82HFmDQOlxtkH2YM10zas2qwL0Qkkjc6D6w-L7fWd0ek3xWkgYLxTxWme=ei4=DFYP9qPocp3S7qD7lAC-TDpxzA32dM5h6M3o0M3hz7DOXBkDaqLOXwNLwQf28AaD7kI0YchWztpWwMTylUcrvr3rf0Z8LlarRp9-YkHdDaFUngR-sATb412rWBuWziuzl7HOIcY5vWTh4Bnh6atGtO7Wn8oG88NW8WTUz7gaai57yvb0w-TDa6e10a0VstF2v75jWrL7z8NyZS3NZF32ZlBgyF4DnKNmgBFrS2L-LwwG5hk83bpoDA0-n7gxzOF76aYkOQpbBQex-_gxwB6znaYOZorhGM083okTzOgWWDT2I7Y2nKNxDsYWUwL2fAt-vM3odM3=dMD9Iiwozi8bDZZN8myhvAkywrabEvV0EO92g-3t3ZZmYMkmIvIxHrkyDA4SsNp2vcLt-k426ksD8A32f6MoE7PdZoT8LUO-T3C2o7L680kNtk62zA12nbK73VZx0kI8fa9xlM52ldN=ESeW8WZxz5axn25SYMs2Za3h08Z0Ikvh8DkyacLW4kayEMY=a_t0Igeow7Ha4gaWUkum=kgnWAXr6yplzZ4-Ia5oaOHtBwBx86N2Tk4-goBt3rYe-ppkZB9-Yxe8VGQoDkHkU51h-Wn2qOe-IVsGUIXS-mmWgOYVngBVsoHVnleoLxLrXVRtp7NUsVLjDAR9v8LGeeVgE8A0UkT=ekeGlAhVLM310kuycrcWXiIx6lDxZ7s-fkY0Q751lAe-cr4dekuzH9n0IgTMf7FmtZSqs=tkzvNtI7ctv6bhTkio7yT8Lkk68WTxnrs-BDb=DdFmXkm2p8zxLwLiHi52Da6yEoFoES0Gzzc06ZDxz8b-IfYznLLSziLwE8NhYMDNzcKoao_Uz7hrfWbxQZD0wvDDfII=whpDEgB2nag0TVD0UQn=EO1xtStxtvehWAXGzqI2wMY2wkL2nr_hzs42IawhXs3-nWkS8eQ28gDVL-ZhtLpD0lDU6oTWW6NGtkktsOKccBa2n7tzQ0DyEyra5pbVYAFVsF4-eqNcZashjay0ekBoErTzq0khz8jDei3TbaD-vA3xkbpmqppVRMLqn78VifNxz7H087LyExNx81Xya7kxZZDVOEY-IiBhncNAftprES_dlmwW0Bb0zg3=EQbSLrLYYMH8Ti4=wMThXkF05BpywOB=E7XrIiU0_BNWfy42n1mYn0p0veX7XBsDEskCvM3DPDeEcBw8nMb6ewtx68LV3lNmz7kGtkg0Qlu23M92fk8luA1-Hauhni3xtfL=wwN2bx42gOYyei3Sz7lxg1Q2bAHzD2e=0k9WbZbho3uDZkDkElNmNOL09OgowWFxt-Z=EaQ8scsoZSkAGMrXfWH8ntuD8A9dzBgWzBBL8mL6ntuoE7F-TNTdvMv2Q76x-mpYLMaoEpS-feXka0DXR3cxXogycYM=wMYMYkFoVAB2QOaqp6skDOPrVAgA7VT0QKNo5B6oLyDh-kw0Z-SjZbpr7YakD9b=wM3rz3w2Vpp2LgBtZrt48MhhSXZ2L0Td8wY3LYy0tZT-gAT2nz6Yn7L2vk8-Dks2ESg-HiayEU6WE7Dowy3-nDp9I7L94p4d8d8=ro80fMs0Xkc-Lrz-IOloZkbZzsl7l7BxE6N8bA52wyb-3auDUw10zOQSLkF8qpZAbyZyEvL8LMNCU57VVA3z-Mg2IpThIaL8s_grzN08sOu9X=Qx4rYslB47qkkWXDZ-IsH2Wz0S3OgWRmLxIab0kZZ2G3Do6mEAWA4bTp3yDZp2Q74hzv6cckhW68NWE76-ZzXAVr9bPSboezPblgu2sog7E7BlzoB=EB32bFl18mOG5Y3h76y-Xk3081XrTgibacNDZ7LtIOFSp0kxzi_=EpRaIhekcXD8RgTh60DTZsBDlrTAfYB2Li9SIKt03ob-3SsAsO30bk3-vWFzcBArn1h0zik2sOnhsOkDDAbhfMDSI7Dbzi80zWS=ldpOZkQ--Mg1qxUcpBDywx0oEOHG-GcklymPMPC2fr5SzOfbQ792uAuhzSLhsYeo_gHoE7eDexm8niB=lgv9v7f=l0e9bWsTfrL6ZiktYagKnOFGLZSWlBc7zAMbDxgT9OlxUDSeDtV-lQS1UiTh6aToZaa0UpDzTDb3vYZTlhpW94aSta4ozach4Ag0LrQLatDGayp8niT7LtpVLrgdDWbN38EWZM0-rypbbk3=E8d=ekhfg03yaODjtguyaOg7wMgjlMRDnZbyEg_ozrH0d7Lhza3xn7brIsg-aOChtr02ucbecYaklMgx=xIowZDWpDTjQaQDlA9DIg9hfxuxzKg77Vu-=94s8wDr-pphUppD3Su2wyNyEMv7wM3xzykh8mLQbiYGt=4oZM6h5Qk2E8XzZleyrxLUbFX-gruG87Hhna5SnLwGtO8ylMD2VATGziI27OsWzqNkE8Ljl7s9gFahW3DoDakGtM4hI_Imn7HrekBDlAkWZa9VR78hzaw-n_58VwN2=xFol6lSXiTxtgkD0a7DESXy07HhzVpxZ8k8nMBAIncmqwZowMl46Mn0bx5xRBL2n740IYkoeO2=Da06a7sGEaN7U5H0GmkyEKknVDyeYwLzES4xUkb2kosGzgsVLw0rINL05g0h8yh2VmwGWo3oEMkesVBxt-a78ypGIqed7o5ita_yekk8sW32bWp=ENkhqYadnr1Ggxv8Rg0Kztp2fyp0tkk=lx5jErBj8Agx6MkkQZZxEfWh68N-ZSwA8DdoZavkZA5o8ABoZwN2OQS83fTrlAs-=SQQqkB0H0T2qB6xtHpx8Ym6VDyhYrk2E7bkwxkhYrbVfMFGEkTxvAY-3S3WzuXW6MX=EVTNElZ2zZumZDuU0DS-bwzAlAbD0aYiTSB2qBxkvcdWdkIhW41Gni8xo2LlEqieYafAzOQ2Yk96YhD-XeuA5Wb2Wkaqw7F2ztLG6oa8v8eYNoayEGEGIg8Dl1ttQaDALyuh402oEAz0TwNk6ZS8Lr5-n7vVsMQoakb2Q7MeIOMx7OX2Ei5kDABRIsFxWDemYaTKo35DI7TbXkk=lWZ-4BC0lDD-kk4mv6LxL8Mkm7kGzZbxE3b0IVb-ToT6dDpDI3fW7qekcB_0grbAAaTnIOlwG3L7na8A75N8f6B2OBkLpkYW7Vp0Io5D--pDDWi0HBMyaOY-4BsoekFpEagWyZn0vMYon=r0gqL0pAOtIat207N5WA52z7ihSkBhUk4mHi3x8A4-dypcqpbyZDT8fgCxobNULe89IZTlfAx-nKNyE0Z-YkMbEfEwtlaA7okxnhpk_kcUnx9-cBvb0gsrIfkW87LDGMrdD6NWQW7xZte8naDV3772PwirHYwhTkihQZDWoBnAdkTecBTx275h8B30-rB=wMDG7ALfv7pdc-T2QHF8Or1NE2iylXXzE7g237kALaByEgBdz7B2Qg3rISTbeku0lA3xUisxQOgyEanjl6qxqVZ=a6hzDxkWUgp2ISBVb6k6Zle0zaTIDkLSekQWIqOWz7DBIoiWpk4xZSYbEcpG8AmjtMHtLaQx8r8x-Zp=lMT70FXWEiFUtMkxto0DTYqGZ7_xZ0FWukBTTkQ06lZ6dO3-Iasx0A4oEtF63Msx6_t6wMaTzM4NldK0yCN8bkgbEgxqTkg0Wkfx0Bj8qYNAsgvAGo32PgvxIZE-HEO-vrvo6cNG5xaj6hp75pp-40knUk56aqq-IOBPaAHkwpTUlWAmnxTW6an=aOrGDgc-YM38nqD-pagA76L2E5iSEseyE736EhktvzC-vA3VsAX-vAt03KNWQSThQau2gka=zAU9gAYWTiu2zmk2LMBhfMBhztpxWlZGtybxYEXx86U7aAs=teObIgBh3ZsU5kQDwMfL7oH=EOeNE8M0jD9xzjd0Zg5DqXX2Vkrxtmohgo3kEO3W4DTGZyh-nWZkRMhxukt63cNt5Bg2Zo_7ZaI2qO6DaOYyd0wSZO5oEMByEiXW8M37nKN0qkQyZk9oEi_Wv7a-vBLx-DnWvBBa7OQ0YaH0XkixzO5zESgj8MbGE7iWzsTm-700sOTzszBx-kFWE73x7rFyaqN' -H 'x-5ku220jw-d: 0' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-channel-id: example' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'x-5ku220jw-uniquestatekey: A0T8ipdpAQAAqwlBr82frHp-xdIOqS8lw0trjR2GWffcuQabeBxJWQ0trFPBAawUHfGuctHLwH8AAOfvAAAAAA==' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'authority: www.example.com' -H 'referer: https://www.example.com/' -H 'dnt: 1' -H 'x-api-key: l7xx944d175ea25f4b9c903a583ea82a1c4c' --data 'username=207731212335&password=testing1&rememberMe=false&application=landing-home-page&site=example&client_id=56f4f55c-79fc-4d2e-8da3-c44a33f666ef&scope=openid&response_type=id_token+swa_token' --compressed
```

Here is my python script

```
import shlex
n = 100
cmd = "curl 'https://www.example.com/api/security/v2/security/authorize' -H 'cookie: check=true; AMCVS_65D316D751E563EC0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=1; mbox=session#d04ba89c86f54832a0585749aa46fc02#1553027525|PC#d04ba89c86f54832a0585749aa46fc02.17_16#1616270465; AMCV_65D316D751E563EC0A490D4C%40AdobeOrg=-1303530583%7CMCIDTS%7C17975%7CMCMID%7C34457710901731852771086841945878510845%7CMCAID%7CNONE%7CMCOPTOUT-1553032862s%7CNONE%7CMCAAMLH-1553630462%7C7%7CMCAAMB-1553630462%7Cj8Odv6LonN4r3an7LhD3WZrU1bUpAkFkkiY1ncBR96t2PTI%7CMCSYNCSOP%7C411-17982%7CvVersion%7C3.3.0; RT="sl=1&ss=1553025660875&tt=3538&obo=0&bcn=%2F%2F36a3fec2.akstat.io%2F&sh=1553025664433%3D1%3A0%3A3538&dm=example.com&si=a71a0de4-27c6-4c1a-806e-137e6c895955&ld=1553025664433"; s_gpv_pn=HP%3ASWA%3Aexample%20Homepage; s_cc=true; akavpau_prod_fullsite=1553025700~id=91b5f44270a63e4fa47dfa8e4734170e' -H 'x-5ku220jw-b: -kzvuvq' -H 'origin: https://www.example.com' -H 'x-5ku220jw-c: A9ruipdpAQAAiGHiRkYp3f3DrWYPKZVfar1Ol_KL0TJZ45wOBoAMWp5BJsvcAawUHfCuctHLwH8AABszAAAAAA==' -H 'x-user-experience-id: f6d89ffd-417e-417c-b380-aa29dc4dac4f' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'x-5ku220jw-a: -gAl0zNf2niU1IiB8nEK-XDD9pte-YgvkwM_28ALqfwo-I7G2gH305BQhtly8TgsQsrw2YyZ8nrF9Crg25vD2nSgDXBgeg-ZkjhbWaqi0vYBtTkg8bMc70Auowl-x5pZx5BuoaOHeIR1o5cN-Lcsx8ALx3oTTakH-EOY269phIOu8naLWzlQXLMgWz756toxlzMTmEMuycrlVf742vrB0IOkAzbTD0MCgc0sVZEXi6Ah18WdWtSHiXwe28MQj80D94r46zzQtnS6xnak83a2bqYPAWAgbgOiYn7HTI7_bYkU6EfDPhVZ-lgLkEsuG3tZ-n7wtaA37fA1h6Mb8LyH=Eae=Z3G0y7sW4B41d3Tbee-a3ZT0sO4GEyhhbAY=Er8ZEVS-Ill09B84I7Y0ng4eDllklgk0uU6=cpT0zsb7sauhWDkAokY2tzY-nATyZ-ZyTs576M38qBgswDbULNFeIz=DDweWlB87ek07VtT2eiDoarQD7OioEVsSpaSrIh9tngu6cB3kaB4kdM420wUtTDpGWbF2npF04rgD0kYTuxThWkkG86L2LNZAfW46Iag-VZZWlMTU6r54RMgxtMBOZSTo7z82HFmDQOlxtkH2YM10zas2qwL0Qkkjc6D6w-L7fWd0ek3xWkgYLxTxWme=ei4=DFYP9qPocp3S7qD7lAC-TDpxzA32dM5h6M3o0M3hz7DOXBkDaqLOXwNLwQf28AaD7kI0YchWztpWwMTylUcrvr3rf0Z8LlarRp9-YkHdDaFUngR-sATb412rWBuWziuzl7HOIcY5vWTh4Bnh6atGtO7Wn8oG88NW8WTUz7gaai57yvb0w-TDa6e10a0VstF2v75jWrL7z8NyZS3NZF32ZlBgyF4DnKNmgBFrS2L-LwwG5hk83bpoDA0-n7gxzOF76aYkOQpbBQex-_gxwB6znaYOZorhGM083okTzOgWWDT2I7Y2nKNxDsYWUwL2fAt-vM3odM3=dMD9Iiwozi8bDZZN8myhvAkywrabEvV0EO92g-3t3ZZmYMkmIvIxHrkyDA4SsNp2vcLt-k426ksD8A32f6MoE7PdZoT8LUO-T3C2o7L680kNtk62zA12nbK73VZx0kI8fa9xlM52ldN=ESeW8WZxz5axn25SYMs2Za3h08Z0Ikvh8DkyacLW4kayEMY=a_t0Igeow7Ha4gaWUkum=kgnWAXr6yplzZ4-Ia5oaOHtBwBx86N2Tk4-goBt3rYe-ppkZB9-Yxe8VGQoDkHkU51h-Wn2qOe-IVsGUIXS-mmWgOYVngBVsoHVnleoLxLrXVRtp7NUsVLjDAR9v8LGeeVgE8A0UkT=ekeGlAhVLM310kuycrcWXiIx6lDxZ7s-fkY0Q751lAe-cr4dekuzH9n0IgTMf7FmtZSqs=tkzvNtI7ctv6bhTkio7yT8Lkk68WTxnrs-BDb=DdFmXkm2p8zxLwLiHi52Da6yEoFoES0Gzzc06ZDxz8b-IfYznLLSziLwE8NhYMDNzcKoao_Uz7hrfWbxQZD0wvDDfII=whpDEgB2nag0TVD0UQn=EO1xtStxtvehWAXGzqI2wMY2wkL2nr_hzs42IawhXs3-nWkS8eQ28gDVL-ZhtLpD0lDU6oTWW6NGtkktsOKccBa2n7tzQ0DyEyra5pbVYAFVsF4-eqNcZashjay0ekBoErTzq0khz8jDei3TbaD-vA3xkbpmqppVRMLqn78VifNxz7H087LyExNx81Xya7kxZZDVOEY-IiBhncNAftprES_dlmwW0Bb0zg3=EQbSLrLYYMH8Ti4=wMThXkF05BpywOB=E7XrIiU0_BNWfy42n1mYn0p0veX7XBsDEskCvM3DPDeEcBw8nMb6ewtx68LV3lNmz7kGtkg0Qlu23M92fk8luA1-Hauhni3xtfL=wwN2bx42gOYyei3Sz7lxg1Q2bAHzD2e=0k9WbZbho3uDZkDkElNmNOL09OgowWFxt-Z=EaQ8scsoZSkAGMrXfWH8ntuD8A9dzBgWzBBL8mL6ntuoE7F-TNTdvMv2Q76x-mpYLMaoEpS-feXka0DXR3cxXogycYM=wMYMYkFoVAB2QOaqp6skDOPrVAgA7VT0QKNo5B6oLyDh-kw0Z-SjZbpr7YakD9b=wM3rz3w2Vpp2LgBtZrt48MhhSXZ2L0Td8wY3LYy0tZT-gAT2nz6Yn7L2vk8-Dks2ESg-HiayEU6WE7Dowy3-nDp9I7L94p4d8d8=ro80fMs0Xkc-Lrz-IOloZkbZzsl7l7BxE6N8bA52wyb-3auDUw10zOQSLkF8qpZAbyZyEvL8LMNCU57VVA3z-Mg2IpThIaL8s_grzN08sOu9X=Qx4rYslB47qkkWXDZ-IsH2Wz0S3OgWRmLxIab0kZZ2G3Do6mEAWA4bTp3yDZp2Q74hzv6cckhW68NWE76-ZzXAVr9bPSboezPblgu2sog7E7BlzoB=EB32bFl18mOG5Y3h76y-Xk3081XrTgibacNDZ7LtIOFSp0kxzi_=EpRaIhekcXD8RgTh60DTZsBDlrTAfYB2Li9SIKt03ob-3SsAsO30bk3-vWFzcBArn1h0zik2sOnhsOkDDAbhfMDSI7Dbzi80zWS=ldpOZkQ--Mg1qxUcpBDywx0oEOHG-GcklymPMPC2fr5SzOfbQ792uAuhzSLhsYeo_gHoE7eDexm8niB=lgv9v7f=l0e9bWsTfrL6ZiktYagKnOFGLZSWlBc7zAMbDxgT9OlxUDSeDtV-lQS1UiTh6aToZaa0UpDzTDb3vYZTlhpW94aSta4ozach4Ag0LrQLatDGayp8niT7LtpVLrgdDWbN38EWZM0-rypbbk3=E8d=ekhfg03yaODjtguyaOg7wMgjlMRDnZbyEg_ozrH0d7Lhza3xn7brIsg-aOChtr02ucbecYaklMgx=xIowZDWpDTjQaQDlA9DIg9hfxuxzKg77Vu-=94s8wDr-pphUppD3Su2wyNyEMv7wM3xzykh8mLQbiYGt=4oZM6h5Qk2E8XzZleyrxLUbFX-gruG87Hhna5SnLwGtO8ylMD2VATGziI27OsWzqNkE8Ljl7s9gFahW3DoDakGtM4hI_Imn7HrekBDlAkWZa9VR78hzaw-n_58VwN2=xFol6lSXiTxtgkD0a7DESXy07HhzVpxZ8k8nMBAIncmqwZowMl46Mn0bx5xRBL2n740IYkoeO2=Da06a7sGEaN7U5H0GmkyEKknVDyeYwLzES4xUkb2kosGzgsVLw0rINL05g0h8yh2VmwGWo3oEMkesVBxt-a78ypGIqed7o5ita_yekk8sW32bWp=ENkhqYadnr1Ggxv8Rg0Kztp2fyp0tkk=lx5jErBj8Agx6MkkQZZxEfWh68N-ZSwA8DdoZavkZA5o8ABoZwN2OQS83fTrlAs-=SQQqkB0H0T2qB6xtHpx8Ym6VDyhYrk2E7bkwxkhYrbVfMFGEkTxvAY-3S3WzuXW6MX=EVTNElZ2zZumZDuU0DS-bwzAlAbD0aYiTSB2qBxkvcdWdkIhW41Gni8xo2LlEqieYafAzOQ2Yk96YhD-XeuA5Wb2Wkaqw7F2ztLG6oa8v8eYNoayEGEGIg8Dl1ttQaDALyuh402oEAz0TwNk6ZS8Lr5-n7vVsMQoakb2Q7MeIOMx7OX2Ei5kDABRIsFxWDemYaTKo35DI7TbXkk=lWZ-4BC0lDD-kk4mv6LxL8Mkm7kGzZbxE3b0IVb-ToT6dDpDI3fW7qekcB_0grbAAaTnIOlwG3L7na8A75N8f6B2OBkLpkYW7Vp0Io5D--pDDWi0HBMyaOY-4BsoekFpEagWyZn0vMYon=r0gqL0pAOtIat207N5WA52z7ihSkBhUk4mHi3x8A4-dypcqpbyZDT8fgCxobNULe89IZTlfAx-nKNyE0Z-YkMbEfEwtlaA7okxnhpk_kcUnx9-cBvb0gsrIfkW87LDGMrdD6NWQW7xZte8naDV3772PwirHYwhTkihQZDWoBnAdkTecBTx275h8B30-rB=wMDG7ALfv7pdc-T2QHF8Or1NE2iylXXzE7g237kALaByEgBdz7B2Qg3rISTbeku0lA3xUisxQOgyEanjl6qxqVZ=a6hzDxkWUgp2ISBVb6k6Zle0zaTIDkLSekQWIqOWz7DBIoiWpk4xZSYbEcpG8AmjtMHtLaQx8r8x-Zp=lMT70FXWEiFUtMkxto0DTYqGZ7_xZ0FWukBTTkQ06lZ6dO3-Iasx0A4oEtF63Msx6_t6wMaTzM4NldK0yCN8bkgbEgxqTkg0Wkfx0Bj8qYNAsgvAGo32PgvxIZE-HEO-vrvo6cNG5xaj6hp75pp-40knUk56aqq-IOBPaAHkwpTUlWAmnxTW6an=aOrGDgc-YM38nqD-pagA76L2E5iSEseyE736EhktvzC-vA3VsAX-vAt03KNWQSThQau2gka=zAU9gAYWTiu2zmk2LMBhfMBhztpxWlZGtybxYEXx86U7aAs=teObIgBh3ZsU5kQDwMfL7oH=EOeNE8M0jD9xzjd0Zg5DqXX2Vkrxtmohgo3kEO3W4DTGZyh-nWZkRMhxukt63cNt5Bg2Zo_7ZaI2qO6DaOYyd0wSZO5oEMByEiXW8M37nKN0qkQyZk9oEi_Wv7a-vBLx-DnWvBBa7OQ0YaH0XkixzO5zESgj8MbGE7iWzsTm-700sOTzszBx-kFWE73x7rFyaqN' -H 'x-5ku220jw-d: 0' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-channel-id: example' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'x-5ku220jw-uniquestatekey: A0T8ipdpAQAAqwlBr82frHp-xdIOqS8lw0trjR2GWffcuQabeBxJWQ0trFPBAawUHfGuctHLwH8AAOfvAAAAAA==' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'authority: www.example.com' -H 'referer: https://www.example.com/' -H 'dnt: 1' -H 'x-api-key: l7xx944d175ea25f4b9c903a583ea82a1c4c' --data 'username=20773121235&password=testing&rememberMe=false&application=landing-home-page&site=example&client_id=56f4f55c-79fc-4d2e-8da3-c44a33f666ef&scope=openid&response_type=id_token+swa_token' --compressed"

x=0

for x in range(n): # or xrange if you are on 2.X

    args = shlex.split(cmd)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use python to execute a curl command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491090/how-to-use-python-to-execute-a-curl-command)

Comment: I think you have some sensitive information in that enormous string, which you may want to scrub. As far as running this 100 times, I don't think the shlex package is doing what you are hoping. If you just need to exec a new process you can do that using os.spawn().

Answer (score 1):

There are double quotes embedded your curl command:

```
cmd = ​​​​"curl 'https://www.example.com/api/security/v2/security/authorize' -H 'cookie: check=true; [snip] RT="sl=1&ss=1553025660875&tt=3538&obo=0&bcn=%2F%2F36a3fec2.akstat.io%2F&sh=1553025664433%3D1%3A0%3A3538&dm=example.com&si=a71a0de4-27c6-4c1a-806e-137e6c895955&ld=1553025664433"; [snip] --compressed"
```

So you need to enclose the command in triple quotes rather than double:

```
cmd = ​​​​"""curl 'https://www.example.com/api/security/v2/security/authorize' -H 'cookie: check=true; [snip] RT="sl=1&ss=1553025660875&tt=3538&obo=0&bcn=%2F%2F36a3fec2.akstat.io%2F&sh=1553025664433%3D1%3A0%3A3538&dm=example.com&si=a71a0de4-27c6-4c1a-806e-137e6c895955&ld=1553025664433"; [snip] --compressed"""
```

or escape the double-quotes using the "\" character:

```
cmd = ​​​​"curl 'https://www.example.com/api/security/v2/security/authorize' -H 'cookie: check=true; [snip] RT=\"sl=1&ss=1553025660875&tt=3538&obo=0&bcn=%2F%2F36a3fec2.akstat.io%2F&sh=1553025664433%3D1%3A0%3A3538&dm=example.com&si=a71a0de4-27c6-4c1a-806e-137e6c895955&ld=1553025664433\"; [snip] --compressed"
```

Personally I'd use the triple-quotes, so you can cut-and-paste the command from your shell.