# How i can find duration of video using google photos API? (iOS/ Swift)

Tags: ios, kotlin, google-photos, google-photos-api

The Google Photos library API does not return the duration of a video. API provides a lot of misc information like camera model and other stuff, but missing very basic things, like video duration, archive status and file size

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the file uri you could try something like this:

#### Android | Kotlin

```
fun getFileDuration(context: Context, uri: Uri): Int {
    try {
        val metadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        metadataRetriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
        val durationStr = metadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)
        if (durationStr != null) return Integer.parseInt(durationStr)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.w("getFileDuration", "Error getting duration of file with uri $uri with ${e.message}")
    }
    return 0
}
```

#### iOS | Swift

```
func getFileDuration(_ uri: URL) -> Int {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: uri)
    let audioDuration = asset.duration.seconds * 1000
    return Int(audioDuration)
}
```

Comment: How can I get in iOS?

Comment: @Vishal I updated my answer to include both Android & iOS example

Comment: Okay thanks, I've tried with productUrl and baseUrl, but still it is return 0.

Comment: My answer is valid only if you have a uri for a file saved locally on the device. For external urls using google photo apis, this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56046574/retrieve-file-size-for-videos-stored-on-google-photos

Comment: Okay let me review that stuff.