# How to create a function in python equivalent to this curl call?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, postman

I'm facing an issue with the code below:

```
!curl -X POST \
      -H 'Content-Type':'application/json' \
      -d '{"data":[[4]]}' \
      http://0.0.0.0/score
```

How can I convert this code into a Python function or using Postman?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491090/how-to-use-python-to-execute-a-curl-command also!

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

payload = {
    "data": [[4]]
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
}

server_url = 'http://0.0.0.0/score'

requests.post(server_url, json = payload, headers = headers)
```

should be roughly equivalent to your curl command.

Otherwise, to "translate" curl into Python commands you could use tools like https://curl.trillworks.com/#python.

Postman has a convenient ["import" tool](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collections/data_formats/#importing-curl) to import `curl` commands like yours (pasting your command as raw text).
The result can also be ["exported" into Python code](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/) using Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest equivalent (with `requests` lib) will look like this:

```py
import requests  # pip install requests
r = requests.post("http://0.0.0.0/score", json={"data":[[4]]})
```

`requests` will automatically set appropriate `Content-Type` header for this request.

---

Note that there will still be some differences in request headers because `curl` and `requests` always set their own set of headers implicitly.

Your `curl` command will send this set of headers:

```
"Accept": "*/*",
"Content-Length": "8",  # not the actual content length
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Host": "httpbin.org",  # for testing purposes
"User-Agent": "curl/7.47.0"
```

And `requests` headers will look like that:

```
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
"Host": "httpbin.org",
"User-Agent": "python-requests/2.22.0",
"Content-Length": "8",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

So you can manually specify `User-Agent` header in `headers=` keyword argument if needed.
But compression will still be used.