# Imitating curl command with python requests

Tags: python, curl

I run curl command, something like this:

```
curl --tlsv1.2 -k -i -X POST -d 'payload={<json-payload>}' https://url.com:/handles/handle1
```

It was working perfectly. Now I need to imitate this in python. Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50704456/1317018) solution, I tried running this in python console:

```
>>> import requests
>>> data = 'payload={<json-payload>}'
>>> headers = {'Content-type':'application/json'}
>>> response = requests.post('https://url.com:/handles/handle',headers=headers,data=data)
```

But getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, inpost
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /handles/handle (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)'),))
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You're probably using a self-signed certificate for that service. Add `verify=False` to your request and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)

Answer (score 2):

For ignoring TLS errors, like `-k` (`--insecure`) in `curl`, you need to use the `verify=False` paramter.

And to pass the POST data, use a `dict`:

```
data = {'payload': <json-payload>}
```

Now your request becomes:

```
requests.post('https://url.com:/handles/handle', headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
```

If you want your POST `data` to be JSON serialized, use the `json` parameter instead of `data`:

```
requests.post('https://url.com:/handles/handle', headers=headers, json=data, verify=False)
```

Comment: Getting `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)`

Comment: @anir Did you use `verify=False`?

Comment: @anir That's weird. What `requests` version are you on? Also please add the full traceback to your question.

Comment: I am running this in jupyter notebook hosted in our development environment. Unfortunately this is the only way we can do development directly in our dev environment. I am not able to get detailed stack trace. Is it possible to get it in jupyter? This is how it look currently: [image](https://i.postimg.cc/vmKTggRd/jupyter.png)