# using requests to get data from API from curl in python

Tags: python

I would like to try to get data from this [api](https://www.makcorps.com/documentation/#track-plane)

I followed the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491090/how-to-use-python-to-execute-a-curl-command) but it does not return any data to me. My code look like this.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.makcorps.com/free/bali/search?key=JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MTc2NzczNjAsImlkZW50aXR5IjozLCJuYmYiOjE1MTc2NzczNjAsImV4cCI6MTUxNzY3OTE2MH0.ytSqQj3VDymEaJz9EIdskWELwDQZRD1Dbo6TuHaPz9U"
data = requests.get(url).json
```

I'm a newbie to working with APIs, may i have your suggestions what went wrong?

Comment: You probably shouldn't expose your JWT to the Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send the JWT token in an HTTP header, not as part of the querystring. Also `.json()` is a *method*, you should call it by appending parentheses:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.makcorps.com/free/bali"
headers = {"Authorization": "JWT <Your JWT Token>"}

print(requests.get(url, headers=headers).json())
```