# Is it possible to download an artifact from Artifactory through Django?

Tags: django, get, artifactory

I have a question regarding the possibility of downloading an artifact from Artifactory through Django.

Is it possible to use a get request using requests like :

```
import requests
r = requests.get(http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/0.9.9/logback-classic-0.9.9.jar?skipUpdateStats=true)
```

or is there another way to download the artifact in python?

Answer (score 0):

If curl works to download the artifact with the URL then the requests library does have sufficient functions that support the curl request. I would recommend referring to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491090/how-to-use-python-to-execute-a-curl-command) for more info.