# what was the reason to get error and how can correct?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

When i import below code in terminal thats fine

```
import pokitdok
```

but when i  try that in pycharm i get below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rponnapureddy/Desktop/ramnath/pok.py", line 3, in <module>
import pokitdok
File "/home/rponnapureddy/Desktop/ramnath/pokitdok.py", line 30, in  <module>
url = json.loads(url)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py",  line 505, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

already installed simple json also
    sudo pip install simplejson
and one more thing is in terminal and pycharm both using same python version 2.7.6 only then why did that error

Comment: We'd need to see the contents of `/home/rponnapureddy/Desktop/ramnath/pokitdok.py` (as well as the contents of whatever json you're trying to decode) -- but looks like you have a malformed json.

Comment: Are you trying to pass a *URL* to `json.loads()` there? `json.loads()` cannot load data from the web for you, you'd need to load it with another library first, then pass the *resulting downloaded text* into that function instead.

Comment: See [Python urllib2: Receive JSON response from url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13921910)

Comment: i did not try any json functions . when i import "import pokidik" i got above error

Comment: `File "/home/rponnapureddy/Desktop/ramnath/pokitdok.py", line 30, in  <module> url = json.loads(url)` says that you did try to do it inside pokidik