# Python download multiple mp4 files from URLs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have URLs in JSON format which contain a lot of .mp4 file URLs, is there a way to use Python to scan the URLs and download all .mp4 files using a loop and urlib -request?

For downloading 1 file with exact URL, the below code works, but my issue is that `url.json` contains 100 videos.

```
import urllib
urllib.url_retrive("http://example.com/helo.mp4","/var/opt")
```

Is there a module that will scan the page and get all .mp4 URLs and loop and download each one?

Comment: `import json`, and go from there

Comment: I got this part , but my main concern here is i've 100 videos on that json body url , how parse it and not to pass 100  urllib.url_retrive

Comment: If you have 100 files to download, you'll eventually have to `url_retrieve()` 100 times, right?

Comment: @Vlad true looping it and parsing the problem

Comment: It's not really clear what the format of the links is. Is the JSON file a bunch of links to pages with HTML that have the mp4 links on them or are the mp4 links in the JSON itself?

Answer (score 3):

Break down this problem first.

First, it's downloading JSON from a URL and parsing it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13921930/230340

Then, it's downloading files. There are some great solutions right here: [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

The whole process may look like this:

```
import urllib, urllib2
import json
import uuid

# download and parse JSON
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://someprovider/of.json')
data = json.load(response)

# data.links is the array of download links, rename it to fit your JSON.
for link in data.links:
  urllib.url_retrive(link, "/var/opt")
```

Comment: I got this part , but my main concern here is i've 100 videos on that json body url , how parse it and not to pass 100 urllib.url_retrive

Comment: @Jecki First, you load the download the JSON and parse it. Only then you begin looping over the files and downloading them.

Comment: thats help me alot ill take it from here and build the rest of the code.

Comment: @Jecki `urllib.url_retrieve` is your download function. If you want to download a 100 files, you must call it a 100 times. (Sorry, I didn't get you the first time)